# iPhone X status bar height

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I have developed an app without `autoLayout` or `interface-builder`, all by code. It runs ok in all `iPhones` except `iPhone X` where the top bar stays under the new black thing in the middle.

It's possible to get that height by code, so I can shift my `Navigationbar` that height down and all runs normal ?

The solutions I see, they use auto layout.

I just want the get the distance to shift it down..

Answer (score 15):

In my Swift app, I get the `frame` of the status bar with

Swift: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame`

Objective-C: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame`

That's a `CGRect`, so you can get its height by doing `size.height` on that. So, altogether, you can do this in Objective-C:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Answer (score 10):

You can always get the status bar height with or without status bar hidden by:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.top
```

and the home screen indicator

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

---

**If it's landscape the value would change**

and `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is there also

Comment: Note that the safe area insets include things like toolbars and navigation bars. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets

Comment: 'safeAreaInsets' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer