# Change status bar height, based on if the device is an iPhone X or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

In my application, I use a custom pod called MMDrawerController, to create a dummy status bar, unfortunately in the pod the status bar's height is always set to **20**.

In order to fix this issue I have written the following code:

**App delegate**

```
MMDrawerController *mmdrawer = [[MMDrawerController alloc]init];


//UPDATE IPHONE X STATUS BAR
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (screenSize.height == 812.0f) {
        NSLog(@"DEVICE NAME : iPhone X");
        self.iphoneXHeight = -45.0;
        self.iphoneXHeightPos = 45.0;
        mmdrawer.height = 40;
    }
    else {

        self.iphoneXHeight = -20.0;
        self.iphoneXHeightPos = 20.0;
        mmdrawer.height = 20;


    }
}
```

**MMDrawerController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat height;
```

**MMDrawerController.m**

```
  _dummyStatusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), self.height)];
```

**Problem:**

When I run my code the `height` property is always 0, would appreciate it if someone can point out what I am doing wrong here and how would I be able access the height property and modify it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone X status bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775477/iphone-x-status-bar-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use fixed height for the status bar, you can get the height with this code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this line.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (screenSize.height == 812.0f) {
    NSLog(@"DEVICE NAME : iPhone X");
    self.iphoneXHeight = -45.0;
    self.iphoneXHeightPos = 45.0;
    mmdrawer.height = 40;
}
```

With this one:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
  // determine screen size
int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

switch (screenHeight) {
        // iPhone 5s
    case 568:
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C");
        break;
        // iPhone 6
    case 667:
        NSLog(@"iPhone 6/6S/7/8");
        break;
        // iPhone 6 Plus
    case 736:
        NSLog(@"iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+");
        break;
        // iPhone X
    case 814:
        NSLog(@"iPhone X");
        break;
    default:
        // it's an iPad
        printf("unknown");
}

}
```